# auto update function results on a page

Tags: javascript, iframe

Ok, first off. No jquery, no ajax, just pure javascript. 
I have the following code on a page called text.html.

```
<html><body>
<script>
function live(ID,txt2) {
    var a = document.getElementById(ID);
    a.innerHTML = (txt2);
}
setInterval(live, 250);
a.innerHTML =(txt2);
</script>
<div id="txt1">Live</div><p />
</body></html>
```

I have the following code on live2.html

```
<html>
  <body>
<p />
<iframe width="400" height="50" src="text.html" name="frameA" id="frameA"></iframe><p />        
<input type="button" value="Live" onClick="document.getElementById('frameA').contentWindow.live('txt1','L I V E')">
<input type="button" value="Rebroadcast" onClick="document.getElementById('frameA').contentWindow.live('txt1','Rebroadcast')"><br />
 <a href="text.html" target="frameA">text</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

The current code works exactly as I wanted it to by updating the information in an iframe. My issue is this. If someone visits text.html directly, I want them to be able to see whatever I've changed that document to. 
Example:
I click on a button and the text in the iframe now says rebroadcast.
Someone else visits text.html and they also see rebroadcast. If while they are looking at text.html, I hit the live button, the text.html page will update with the word live. 
I can do PHP scripting on this as well. I have tried jquery and have issues with getting it to work correctly and I don't really have the knowledge or access to implement much of anything else.
This is an on-going project. The end result, I hope, will be an iframe that I can update while not actually being on the same page that the frame is located on. (same domain tho) The content will be anything from images, to youtube embeds and pictures. I'm trying to get a more comprehensive idea of how this language works and that's why I'm taking it one step at a time. I have no issue with visiting tutorials or looking at pre-made solutions. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: If you have no issue with "pre-made solutions", what's wrong with jQuery and similar libraries?

Comment: I've tried a couple of jquery solutions that either pulls the jquery from a server or having it directly on the page and I just haven't gotten it to work right. I'm also using this to learn javascript and php better. I would be tearing the pre-made solutions apart and ultimately doing the programming myself from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off this is what happens when someone learning programming languages doesn't fully comprehend what a language can and can't do. The original idea was to let a specific group of people know when it was a re-broadcast or when the show was live. I wanted the control of when to change that information to only be available to an admin of sorts. In the end the entire idea got scrapped and entirely impractical. The solution, essentially, doesn't exist in the context of the way I wanted to accomplish this. Years later...
The solution is to have live and rebroadcast inside div tags with CSS. Then use a JavaScript function to change the attributes of the divs to either be hidden or shown. The button or or link would need to exist on the same page as the live or rebroadcast text. This would also mean that there is no need for a separate frame. To have this element controlled from outside the page it's on could only be done by storing a value somewhere else and having that value periodically checked. 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9goxv5aj/)

The Script:

```
var x = document.getElementById("txt1");
var y = document.getElementById("txt2");


function htext() {
    x.style.visibility = 'visible';
    y.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function stext() {
    x.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    y.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function ctext() {
    var z = getComputedStyle(x).getPropertyValue("visibility");
    if (z != 'hidden') {
        stext();
    } else if (z != 'visible') {
        htext();
    }
}
```

The CSS:

```
#txt1 {
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-left:0px;
}
#txt2 {
    visibility:visible;
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<span id="txt1">Live</span>

<span id="txt2">Rebroadcast</span>

<br />
<a href="javascript://" onclick="ctext();">click</a>
```

To be honest. I'm not entirely sure of the programming needed to store information somewhere else and have a check to see if certain conditions are true. The program above will essentially hide and show a div. I could probably go a step further and use JQuery to create and remove the actual div itself. In the end this is essentially close to the solution I ended up using and then later on discarding and giving up on the project.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm probably missing something. Users will always see the text "Live" because that's what's hard-coded in text.html. It doesn't matter if you change the text through JavaScript since it will only affect the browser that you're seeing. You need to save it to a persistence storage (ie. database) and dynamically display it on the page.

Comment: +1 If you want to transfer data (the current url of the iframe content) from one client to another client (your browser to their browser) then you will need to involve a server side solution and update checking from the other clients to see if the url has changed.

Comment: So if I had a field in a database then I could change the contents of that field and the page would update with the results dynamically?

Comment: Say if you create a table in your database with a column called "status", which represents "live" or "rebroadcast". Every time you click a button on live2.html, you need to update status in the database accordingly; Every time you display text.html, you need to grab the status from the database.

A side from that, since you're implementing dynamic webpages, you need to use text.php or your language of choice.

Comment: So, if I have a table in a database that holds a value and the button changes that value, then I can create a script that checks the value and then displays the result. I'm guessing I could expand that so that a form on a page populates data fields in a table and then those pieces of data can be parsed in a page.

Comment: sounds right, you can look up MVC design pattern for better code separation.

Answer (score 0):

live2.html can use AJAX to send the changes to the server, which can then update live.html. But this is a poor way to do it, since it means that the contents of live.html are updated outside of your version control and/or content management system.  It's better to use a real database and generate the page dynamically, as suke said.

Comment: Lots of people have been mentioning AjAX so I guess I'm going to have to check that out. Not sure If I'll be able to integrate that into the web server, however.

Comment: --hehe.. I just read up on AJAX. Now I feel like a moron. Any idea where I can find a tutorial or how I would do this using Ajax, or another post that has information that may point me in the right direction?